# Selected item is lost when I right click to MouseBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, selecteditem, inputbinding

I have problem with MouseBinding in WPF.
When I right click mouse to selected item, the forms (UserControl) is open, but selected item is lost (canceled).

Can you help me, please?

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="RightClick" Command="{Binding ShowDWClickOnRightButton}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>

<DataGrid x:Name="DatagridForLogistic" Grid.Row="2" MinWidth="620" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="5"
          Style="{StaticResource MujStyl}" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Light"                            
          ItemsSource="{Binding Stredisko,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"             
          SelectedItem="{Binding MyItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
```

**Command**

```
public ICommand ShowDWClickOnRightButton
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            VMRightButton viewModel = UnityActivator.CreateInstance<VMRightButton>();
            viewModel.Title = String.Format("Action on right click for card {0}", MyItem.CardId).ToString();
            viewModel.NumberOfCard = MyItem.CardId;
            CreateDWRightButton.Raise(new Notification() { ViewModel = viewModel });
        });
    }
}
```

**Properties MyItem**

```
public ENotifiedProperties MyItem
{
    get
    {
        return _entityProperties;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_entityProperties != value)
        {
            _entityProperties = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyItem");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add right click event handler code ?

Comment: Do you mean `MyItem` is null in `ShowDWClickOnRightButton` command?

Comment: yes, MyItem is null